# JAVAFX Text Area is not showing formatted output of the string

Tags: java, javafx-2

Here scenario is program reads output properly and it is also printing properly in the log file but when displying same output on JAVAFX text area its format is getting changed(Its in tabular format) and its not displaying properly.
[image: This is the image of text area]
Below is the output getting written in log file:

```
 ****************PR Deploy Summary Report Start****************
 Folder                   Server                   Type                     Failed                  
 010_StyleSheets          10.5.50.195              SS                       0                       
 010_StyleSheets          10.5.50.195              WS                       0                       
 020_XSL                  10.5.50.195              SS                       0                       
 030_XSLT                 10.5.50.195              SS                       0                       
 040_WebTemplates         10.5.50.195              SS                       0                       

 ****************PR Deploy Summary Report****************
```

Actually when i am copying this from text area and pasting it somewhere else then its agian showing it properly in tabular format.But its not displaying it properly on text area.
There is very simple code written for this as below:

```
DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.appendText(UnixBoxTask.summary.toString());

                DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.end();
```

Here "actLogTArea" is the reference of text area, summary is StringBuilder ...can anybody guess what can be the issue here? any solution if somebody has already faced this? it may be possible that image i have placed in question is not visible.

Comment: Add a CSS style with a non-proportional monospaced font, like Courier, Lucida-Console. You used a font where `m` is larger than an `i`.

Comment: Not getting u clearly...do mean i need to add css style sheet for text area ? if so..can you please tell me how to add it in javafx? FXML

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the font of textArea to generic monospaced one:

```
actLogTArea.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace");
```

To change other font properties (and see limitations) refer to [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: I tried with  DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace"); and DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.setStyle("-fx-font-family: Courier");  still facing same issue

Comment: Maybe try with an id: in fxml: `fx:id="actLogTextArea"` and as you seem to have a global .css: `#actLogTextArea { ... }`. Or with `.text`. _(No experience myself)_

Comment: @Rohan Are you sure that the `setStyle()` line has been executed? I tried myself and worked like as expected.

Comment: @Uluk its working properly now...i just inserted that code in initialize method and its working now...thanks :-)