# Java FX Table View in TextArea

Tags: javafx, tableview, textarea

I currently struggle to get text columns aligned in a TextArea. This is because the items are the result of some calculations with varying number of digits (please see the picture attached). Does anyone know how can we push a TableView in a TextArea or a similar solution? Of course I could display the TableView directly, separated from other information, but it wouldn't be in that natural order as in a log file. Any help, greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZLYL.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried out a monospaced font?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVAFX Text Area is not showing formatted output of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172249/javafx-text-area-is-not-showing-formatted-output-of-the-string)